# Symbolic Link File Information via Command Line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link

Is there any way to grab symbolic file information (or metadata?) via Command Line tool on Windows like that:

[image: File information]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I display a file's hard links from the command line?

Use `fsutil`.

Example:

```
F:\test>fsutil.exe hardlink list C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
\Windows\notepad.exe
\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepadwin_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_9ebebe8614be1470\notepad.exe
\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_cb0f7f2289b0c21a\notepad.exe
\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
```

Usage:

```
F:\test>fsutil hardlink
---- HARDLINK Commands Supported ----

create          Create a hardlink
list            Enumerate hardlinks on a file

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [fsutil](http://ss64.com/nt/fsutil.html) - File and Volume specific commands, Hardlink management, Quota management, USN, Sparse file, Object ID and Reparse point management

Comment: Thank you!!! I want to scan it by PHP, but it needs to "Run as Administrator", how to overcome this?

Comment: @Digerkam Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you again!! it works perfectly and never ask administrator privileges!